# how to launch ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I was working on this tutorial: `https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course_video?id=4562` (you can download the source code)

the VC is launched from appdelegate with the following code:

```
    window = UIWindow()
    window?.rootViewController = StretchyHeaderController(collectionViewLayout: StretchyHeaderLayout())
```

But, I want to launch StretchyHeaderController from another ViewController, not appDelegate.

Here is what I tried:

```
let newViewController = StretchyHeaderController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

But nothing happens. How can I launch StretchyHeaderController?

here is shwat StretchyHeaderController looks like:

```
class StretchyHeaderController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
```

Comment: Is the view controller in which  you are using this code embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: be more specific

Comment: no it is not embedded, it is all done in code

Comment: class StretchyHeaderController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

Comment: If you just start to learn swift, I don't recommend you Brian's tutorials, because usually he doesn't use any storyboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `UINavigationController` to push viewCOntroller in navigation stack. if you are not using `UINavigationController`, then you can present the viewController

```
 let viewController = StretchyHeaderController(collectionViewLayout: StretchyHeaderLayout())

 self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: this worked, thanks.. but i noticed that this implementation you need to specify the header: StretchyHeaderLayout()   , but I also have a footer, which is not showing. DO I need to also specify the footer here?

Comment: Yes you also need to specify it.

Comment: and if this answer helped you, please do a selection and thumbs up :)

Comment: footers are now showing, but I did not have to specify it when launching the VC...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present `StretchyHeaderController` from another View Controller make sure that View Controller is embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

Otherwise nothing will happen.

Try

```swift
print(self.navigationController?)
```

before your code and make sure it's not printing `nil`.